# ListView DataPager is not working

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I have this ListView with a DataPager

```
<asp:ListView ID="ProfilesList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ProfilesList_DataBound" >
               <LayoutTemplate>
                   <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="ContactsDataPager" PageSize="12">
            <Fields>
              <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"
                FirstPageText="|&lt;&lt; " LastPageText=" &gt;&gt;|"
                NextPageText=" &gt; " PreviousPageText=" &lt; " />
            </Fields>
          </asp:DataPager>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="GridBody" style="padding:0; width:910px; border-bottom-style:none;">
                    <tr class="GridHeader" style="text-align:center;">
                        <td style="width:8px; padding-left:5px; border-bottom-style:none; ">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:274px; border-bottom-style:none;">
                            Person Info
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:273px; border-bottom-style:none;">
                            Company Info
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:272px; border-bottom-style:none;">
                            User Attributes
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
              </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
```

Keep in mind this is only the first bit of the ListView as the whole thing is huge.

Anyways the buttons appear, but they do not do anything at all....do I have to do something in my code behind?

Comment: Put your DataPager outside the ListView and then set the DataPager's property PagedControlID to ProfilesList

Answer (score 1):

Extract DataPager from ListView, set PagedControlID property and implement the PagePropertiesChanging method:

```
//set current page startindex, max rows and rebind to false
ContactsDataPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
//rebind List View
BindListView();
```

Take at look at this article:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/paging-listview-using